# Написать функцию JS

Tags: javascript, html

Написать функцию, которая будет принимать в себя два аргумента - `elem(HTMLElement)` и `styleObject(object со стилями)`.
После вызова функции, объекту `elem` должны добавляться `style` свойства из объекта `styleObject`.

```js
var titleNew = document.getElementById("title");

var styleObject = {
  "color": "red",
  "margine": "20 px",
  // "font-size": "18 px",
}

function changStyle(elem, sObject) {
  for (var key in sObject) {
    elem.style.key = sObject[key];
  }
}
changStyle(titleNew, styleObject);
```

```html
<h1 id="title"> JS DOOM TREE</h1>
```

Answer (score 1):

Для обращения к свойствам объекта имена которых заранее неизвестны, Вы можете использовать альтернативный способ обращения - с помощью квадратных скобок. Например так:

```
function changStyle (element, styles) {
 if (element != null && styles != null) {
  for (style in styles) {
   element.style[style] = styles[style];
  }
 }
}
```

Кстати у Вас написано margine, а должен быть margin. Также все имена стилей с тире следует записывать без него. Например: margin-top -> marginTop.

P.S. change пишется с "е" на конце

Comment: я не совсем понял что надо сделать с моим кодом

Comment: @komandorser замените Вашу реализацию функции changStyle() на мою.

Comment: https://codepen.io/sergius00/pen/pPVzeN?editors=1011 
не работает (((
я хочу что бы h1 тегу присваивались стили и менялись цвет и маргин

Comment: @komandorser обновил код.

Comment: @komandorser кстати у Вас написано `margine`, а должен быть `margin`. Также все имена стилей с тире следует записывать без него. Например: `margin-top` -> `marginTop`. P.S. change пишется с "е" на конце.

Comment: если честно - то ничего не понял, можете дать ссылку на кодпен

Comment: @komandorser обновите changStyle()

Comment: спасибо, +1  ! ))

Comment: @komandorser только заменяйте имена с тире: `margin-top` -> `marginTop`

Comment: @wcobalt, перенеси свои комментарии про опечатки и замену тире в ответ

Answer (score 1):

1. Исправить ошибки в объекте.
2. Внести его в style.

```js
var title = document.getElementById("title");

var styleObject = {
  "color": "red",
  "margin": "20px",
}

Object.assign(title.style, styleObject);
```

```html
<h1 id="title">JS DOOM TREE</h1>
```